# Voice transformation in Android

Tags: android, transformation, voice, voice-recording

I am looking for an SDK for Android proving tools to transform the voice.
With iOS, there is this kind of SDK : http://www.izotope.com/tech/izomobile/vocalfx.asp

Do you know something similar ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice transformation in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675370/voice-transformation-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Check out **API DEMOS** from the folder on your drive **android-sdk/samples/apidemos**. Here is one example of **Voice Recognition** there. May be you find it useful.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for voice recognition. He wants to do stuff like pitch-bending and filters.